# Rails 3.2.14 will not run Mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, mongrel

I've seen dozens of links on how to fix this problem (a lot of them from stackoverflow), but nothing seems to work for me.  No matter what I do WEBrick starts up instead of Mongrel.

My environment:

I'm using rvm...

```
rvm 1.21.20 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p448 through rvm.  Confirmed by rvm list...

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p174 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

...and ruby -v...

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

I installed mongrel like this...

```
gem install mongrel --pre
```

I confirmed the correct mongrel gem is in the gem list...

```
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2)
```

I then added this line to my Gemfile...

```
gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
```

I then run bundle install and everything says it's correct, but no matter what I do, when I run rails server I get WEBrick.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My memory is that Rails isn't configured to look for mongrel (even if it's installed).  You can run mongrel directly though.  But you might consider switching to thin.  Works just fine and is recognized by Rails automatically.

http://rubygems.org/gems/thin